# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node' when Using ag-grid angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

ag-grid was used in my project. But today I find an error in the console. it shows that:

> ag-grid.min.js:224 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

Screenshot:

[image: the error in console]

And I also try to duplicate the error in [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Pl9ipD8bGAY27qOHdEhW?p=preview), but I failed.

By the way, when I debug in the local, I found the cause is caused by 
`options.api.setColumnDefs(data.columnHeader);` this is also in the plunker's js file `chartUtil.js`;

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?